# Felix is quick ____ understanding the matter

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, exam-questions

Will it be

"Felix is quick at understanding the matter."

or

"Felix is quick in understanding the matter."?

I think the former will be correct. I have found both answers being reported as correct. For example, [this](https://www.admissions.sattacademy.com/single-question.php?varsity=iu&ques_id=4528) website says that the former is correct, while [this](https://brainly.in/question/47377726) website says the latter is correct. Which one is truly correct?

Comment: Neither of them sound idiomatic to this US English speaker.  I would say "quick **to understand** the matter".

Answer (score -1):

You are right.

Felix is quick **at** understand**ing**...

(Felix is quick **at** maths.)

Comment: I think we say **quick at** a skill, but **quick in** doing something. _Laura was quick on her feet, quick in speech, quick in thought._ (Phyllis Bentley). You could also say **quick to understand**.

Comment: Please answer OP's question. ...quick at understanding or ...quick in understanding? To me, ...quick  understanding.

Comment: I meant 'quick **at**' a skill such as mathematics, but 'quick **in doing** or **to do**' something such as finding, understanding, speaking.

Comment: Kate Bunting
'quick in doing or to do' something such as finding, understanding, speaking.' -- I don't agree.   '...quick  understand' is not incorrect.

Comment: @KateBunting Would you agree that "Felix is quick at understanding the matter" is correct?

Comment: Well, I would use _quick in understanding_ or, better still, _quick to understand_.